# JavaScript(React)- Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'style')

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am working in a project using React Js. When I wrote this, **Syntax:  movieRef.current.style.transform = `translateX(210px)`;** it's not working. It shows an error- can't read 'style'. How can I solve this problem. I have attached my codes here.

```js
import React, { useState, useRef } from "react";
import { useGetMoviesQuery } from "../../services/movieApi";
import SingleMovie from "../SingleMovie/SingleMovie";
import "./MovieRow.scss";
import "../SingleMovie/SingleMovie.scss";
import { MdArrowForwardIos, MdArrowBackIos } from "react-icons/md";

// const MovieRow = ({title}) => {codes}
const MovieRow = (props) => {
  const { title, fetchURI } = props;
  const { data, isLoading } = useGetMoviesQuery(fetchURI);
  const movieRef = useRef();
  // console.log("data:", data);

  if (isLoading) {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1 style={{ textAlign: "center", marginTop: "250px" }}>Loading...</h1>
      </div>
    );
  }
  const handleClick = (direction) => {
    if (direction === "left") {
      movieRef.current.style.transform = `translateX(210px)`;
    }
  };
  return (
    <>
      <div className="movie-row-container">
        <h1>{title}</h1>

        <div className="wrapper">
          <MdArrowForwardIos
            className="slider right-arrow"
            onClick={() => handleClick("right")}
          />
          <div className="movie-row-block" ref={movieRef}>
            {data?.results.map((movie, index) => (
              <SingleMovie key={movie?.id} singleMovie={movie} index={index} />
            ))}
          </div>
          <MdArrowBackIos
            className="slider left-arrow"
            onClick={handleClick("left")}
          />
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default MovieRow;
```

```css
//MovieRow.scss file

h1 {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 100%;
  color: white;
}
// non-global css
.movie-row-container {
  margin-top: 25px;
  margin-left: 22px;
  .wrapper {
    position: relative;
    .slider {
      height: 100%;
      width: 70px;
      background-color: rgba(12, 42, 214, 0.438);
      color: white;
      position: absolute;
      z-index: 99;
      margin: 0 auto;
      cursor: pointer;

      &.right-arrow {
        right: 0;
      }

      &.left-arrow {
        left: 0;
      }
    }
    .movie-row-block {
      display: flex;
      overflow-x: scroll;
      overflow-y: hidden;
      transform: translateX(210px);
    }
  }
  .movie-row-block::-webkit-scrollbar {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

Comment: The error means that `movieRef.current` is undefined. The reason is a bad click handler. `onClick={handleClick("left")}` needs to be `onClick={() => handleClick("left")}` (your code lead to handleClick("left") being executed during rendering; you passed a function call as opposed to a function)

Answer (score 0):

This part is firing infinitely even before the first render, that's why you'll get undefined on `style`:

```
          <MdArrowBackIos
            className="slider left-arrow"
            onClick={handleClick("left")}
          />
```

Change it to this:

```
           <MdArrowBackIos
             className="slider left-arrow"
             onClick={handleClick.bind(undefined, "left")}
           />
```

Comment: This is a very common issue and definitely a duplicate. Please check for those before posting answers.

Comment: okay and thank you for giving me  answer. I am a new learner in the field of MERN.